# MySql: Simple SELECT leads to Error Code 1064

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064, coda

I see myself as a competent MySql-user, but now I have a basic problem with executing queries like `SELECT * FROM User;` and other trivial statements on my new MacBook Pro 15" with Retina Display and `OS X 10.9.2`.

I am trying to develop a web application using `MySql 5.6` and `PHP 5.5` on the server side, but almost every time I write and execute a statement I got the `1064 error code`. I had attempted to do this in `Coda 2` where I make my PHP scripts and MySql Workbench 6.0, but it did not work.

When I right-click on a table in Workbench and select **Select Rows - Limit 1000** or let Wb generate an SQL-statement for me, everything is ok. Even if I copy the statement and modify some parts of the statement, the query gets executed and MySql does not give any error message.

I have checked my PHP document and that the database uses `utf8`. I did look for viable solutions for this problem in the web, but in vain.

Here is the code I tried to execute:

```
1   SELECT * FROM bo14g19.User LIMIT 0, 1000;
2   SELECT * FROM bo14g19.User;
3   SELECT * FROM bo14g19.User;
4   USE bo14g19
5   SELECT * FROM User
6   SELECT * FROM User
```

Line 1, 2, 4, and 6 is ok. Line 1 and 6 is generated by Workbench and line 2 is a direct copy from line 1 without the LIMIT. Line 3, 4, and 5 is manually typed in by hand.

Here you can find a screenshot from Workbench:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4w6v9v3c0vainpx/mysql-workbench-execute-problems.jpg

Is this a known issue?

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: At least post your SQL command.

Comment: And your whole error.

Comment: you're probably using reserved words from MySQL. Post your SQL query please.

Comment: we actually can't guess here, best thing to do in order for you to get proper help is by adding your query, and any relevant code for us to diagnose.

Comment: Were you test it on another mysql-IDE / pma ?

Answer (score -1):

I found the problem! :-) My Keyboard language was set to "Sami", not "Norsk, bokmål"(Norwegian). So stupid and embarrassing, but the symbols and letters are just the same as in Norwegian, so I can`t understand why it didm`t work... The Norwegian and the Sami keyboard look exactly the same.